# Latitude, Longitude, Z Field in CSV format to Raster Map

Tags: python, csv, numpy, maps, weather

```
    L1            L2        L3         L4        LATITUDE   LONGITUDE
-3.627661   -16.376394  6.729712    3.592987    24.813797   -88.901495
-7.223523   -16.020485  2.175032    3.322263    24.6915     -87.84013
-7.556808   -15.840759  1.892859    2.977641    24.694245   -87.868856
-11.385272  -15.460266  9.150633    9.565245    29.965457   -87.565512
-6.31497    -15.221949  3.690079    4.606816    26.119643   -88.410623
-7.728157   -15.004622  7.65388     7.450833    29.968328   -87.596143
```

From this CSV, I have been trying to export this into a raster map using something like this:

```
from scipy import interpolate

lon_list = np.arange(3, 6, 1)
lat_list = np.arange(4, 8, 1)

lon_2d, lat_2d = np.meshgrid(lon_list, lat_list)
grid_array = interpolate.griddata((array[:,-1], array[:,-2]), array[:,0],
                                  (lon_2d, lat_2d))[::-1]
print(grid_array)

>>> [[  nan  7.    6.72]
 [ 6.    5.4   5.6 ]
 [ 4.    3.8   4.  ]
 [ 2.    2.2   2.4 ]]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(grid_array)
```

However, I am still having issues on simply exporting this csv file into raster map like this: 
[Examples of Weather Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohT1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

The module you're looking for is [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) which inherits many of its classes and methods from [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).

This is going to allow you to read data from your csv easily with `df = pandas.read_csv("path/to/file.csv")`

You should be able to populate the other latitude and longitude values than you can interpolate with `df.interpolate()`

Once you convert it to a geopandas dataframe with `gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df)` you'll be open to a world of mapping as easy as `gdf.plot()` or far more elaborate, whatever suits your needs. After you've called that you can save it to your disk with `pyplot.savefig("path/to/raster.tiff")`

You may have to break this question down into several smaller ones to get better help on Stack Overflow, but if you look through the documentation I've linked, you'll have a much better idea of what to do next

Comment: Thank you. I was reading about using matplot lib to show my array of data (output = np.compress(map(pointInBox,output),output,axis=0)
 and came across:  http://www.aosc.umd.edu/~dkleist/docs/pythonTraining/Slides/netCDF4Matplotlib_SSSO.pdf  Pages 51-63. What do you think?

Comment: @Kyle Oh, I see. I have a better idea of the issue, which my answer does not address. If you could edit your question and describe what this data represents and more specifically what your desired output looks like, I'll have a better suggestion.